# Cell type that expresses 90% of the genome

Tags: gene-expression

Cells that are differentiated express the genes that are necessary for their own usage. I've heard that some cell type expresses about 90% of 30,000 proteins that are encoded in the genome. Can anybody tell me what this cell type is?

Comment: Can you point us to a source that says that?

Comment: I'm thinking of thymic medullary cells, but I don't know how many genes they express.

Comment: I've rolled your edit back because it completely changes the meaning of the question and renders the answer irrelevant. If you have a different question, ask it in a new post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the asker stubbornly insists on edits that change the question to something meaningless.

Comment: Please stop editing the question so that the answer gets meaningless and open a new question instead. I will roll back it to the last version where answer makes sense and then lock it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found this paper:

[Danan-Gotthold M, Guyon C, Giraud M, Levanin EY, Abramson J. 2016. Extensive RNA editing and splicing increase immune self-representation diversity in medullary thymic epithelial cells. Genome Biol 17:219.](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-016-1079-9)

> #### Medullary thymic epithelial cells [mTECs] express ~85 % of the entire coding genome
>
> ...to better determine the fraction of genes expressed in mTECs and other mouse tissues, we took advantage of RNA-seq technology... The analysis... revealed that most of the tissues [see below for those tested] express 12,000–14,000 genes (i.e. 60–65 % of the coding genome). The lung and two immunologically privileged sites, brain and testis, were the only tissues that expressed a larger fraction of the genome, in the range of 70–75 %... In line with other recently published studies, the mTEC<sup>hi</sup> population expressed nearly 18,000 genes, which represents ~85 % of the coding genome, while [Aire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoimmune_regulator)-deficient mTECs (AireKO) expressed approximately 15,000 genes, suggesting that Aire is responsible for the induction of ~3000 genes in mTECs. Interestingly, even in the absence of Aire, the mTECs expressed a relatively large fraction of the genome (~75 %), considerably exceeding the overall genome expression in other peripheral tissues. Interestingly, neither [cortical thymic epithelial cells] nor [skin epithelial cells] demonstrated higher overall genome expression than other tissues, suggesting that promiscuous gene expression is indeed unique to the mTECs population.

These cells express such a wide complement of proteins because they are involved in T-cell maturation, specifically [negative selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tolerance#T_cell_tolerance).

---

List of tissues tested in the study:

> brain, testes, liver, kidney, lung, colon, skeletal muscle, spleen, cortical thymic epithelial cells, skin epithelial cells